# Xcode document icon not updating

Tags: xcode, macos, icons, nsdocument

I've created an `.icns` and set it in the Document Types section of my project, but my documents' icons in Finder remain generic. I've noticed that if I change my document type's file extension, the icon displays. Is there a cache I need to clear or some other way to update the icon without changing the file extension?

Answer (score 2):

To force refresh icon put this into your terminal

> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister
>   -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user; killall Dock

Mavericks:

> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister;
>   killall Dock

Comment: The command ran, but the icons did not update. Is there something else I should try?

Comment: Is your program running during the kill? If you are looking for updated icon in finder then you have to relaunch Finder as well. Right click + OPTION button on finder icon

Comment: Aw gosh this didn't update my dock icon either :( Would you be available for a stackoverflow chat? I have been struggling with this issue since November last year: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/160249/created-a-symlink-but-finder-shows-it-as-an-alias?rq=1 If you are available and comfortable I can give you my teamviewer to show you want's going on I would super super appreciate that and you might even discover some new solution :)

Comment: @Tone416 maybe it didnt work but up vote for the effort, otherwise you would have no response till today.